# Define using a constraint a composite FK derived from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bridge relation resolving M:N relationship.

[image: Like this]

How should I write the code for SQL Server using constraint to define a composite FK derived from these two tables?

I tried doing something like this:

```
constraint cat_treat_id_fk
foreign key(cat_id,treat_id)
references cat(cat_id), treat(treat_id)
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You need to create each constraint separately (i.e., you will have two FK constraints in your cat-treat table: Cat_Id references the cat table, and treat_id references the treat table).

Comment: Should your model allow a cat to gorge itself on multiples of a particular treat? If not then in addition to the two, separate, foreign key constraints you might wish to add a unique constraint on `(treat_id, cat_id)`.

Comment: Or, to extend @AlwaysLearning's comment, allow for fat cats by adding a `NumberOfTreats BigInt` column to the intermediate table with a constraint that sets `1` as the lower limit.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical table design for this in SQL Server is:

```
create table Cat_Treat
(
  treat_id int not null references Treat,
  cat_id int not null references Cat,
  constraint pk_Cat_Treat primary key (treat_it,cat_id),
  index ix_Cat_Treat_cat_id (cat_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you draw the edges on that diagram pointing in the wrong directions.

The M:N relationship can be defined as:

```
create table cat_treat (
  treat_id int  not null references treat (treat_id),
  cat_id int  not null references cat (cat_id),
  primary key (treat_id, cat_id)
);
```